What does すれども here mean?
「これからオープンされるんです？」
「いいえ、事情聴取が思いのほか長引いたので準備はすれども、もういいかなと」
The character is asking his bartender friend if he's gonna open the bar after it.
However he replies "No, I got held by the police for so long..."
I'm not sure what how to take the rest? "Regardless of the preparations, I thought of giving up for tonight"? or is it more "I gave up on preparing?"


すれども is the equivalent of するけれど in classical Japanese. See this question for this ども. This is highly old-fashioned/pompous language, and ordinary modern Japanese speakers wouldn't use this in speech.
もういいかな means "that'd be enough", "let's not", or "I think I'll pass". This いい means "unnecessary" or "no thanks" rather than "okay".

So he's saying "I'll do the preparations, but maybe I'll pass (on actually opening the bar)".
